# Class for API call: how to correctly handle token

Tags: python-3.x, api, class

So far, I was using API methods with functions

But now I am trying to build a class with every methods that have an API.

My main concern is about handling correctly the generation of the token. This is a basic authentification with a user/password i send in an xml with the /token resquest.

Once I generate an object, I want to get a token and refresh it when it expires. I want to avoid to get a token to each request I will make.

In the constructor, I put the user, password and root url of the API.
I also put self.token_access = get_token(self)  with get_token the method to request a token.

If I put a refresh token before each request (one method by request), it will work. However, it will refresh the token (add time to the expiration date) but it would like to do so, only if the token is dead.

How would be the most elegant way to do so ?

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please find some details of what I did so far below. This class is working, however, when I will build an API object,if the token expire, it won't manage the refresh of the token...

```
class API:

    def __init__(self,host,user,password):
   
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.token = self.get_token()

    def get_token(self):

        xml = "<userCredentials><login>" +self.user+ "</login><password>" +self.password+ "</password></userCredentials>"
        Response = requests.post(self.host + "tokens", data=xml, headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"})
        if Response.ok:
            print(Response.content)
            root = et.fromstring(Response.content)
            token_session = root.find('tokenId').text
            return token_session
        else:
            Response.raise_for_status()

    def refresh_token(self):
        try:
            requests.put(self.host + "tokens" + "/" + self.token_access, data=xml, headers={"Content-Type": "application/xml"})
            return self.token_access
        except:

            return self.get_token()
        
    def methodap1_1(self):
        ...
```